# VBA: MouseWheel Event in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there any way to scroll a text box with the mouse wheel in PowerPoint? The existing solutions don't seem to address other apps, not PowerPoint.

There is no `MouseWheel` event available.

Comment: Are you able to even create a text box with a scroll bar in PowerPoint? I haven't seen that.

Comment: You need to set ScrollBars parameter of the textbox accordingly

Comment: OK - is there a reason you can't make it look you're scrolling by using built in animations (or just multiple slides that you transition through)? I agree there's no PPT event for mousescroll.

Comment: I don't get your point. I need to scroll a textbox in my custom form with the mouse wheel.

Comment: OK sorry I assumed it was a textbox on a slide. The scrollbar event on a form should work - what have you tried? I assume something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278741.aspx?

Comment: I think you still don't get me. Scroll event is not the same as mouse wheel.

Comment: Looks like the only way to do this is via WinAPI : http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184493

Comment: I'm sorry - you're right. I don't know what's wrong with me.

Comment: @JamieG This is an extremely old solution and no surprise it's not functioning